After replacing a data source, adding a report page to a dashboard blanks out the page?
I'm having a problem data showing after I replaced a data source.
I have a report whose data source is being updated. The original data source was a single large flattened table of millions of rows. I replicated this data source in a new Tableau workbook as a dimensional model by adding all these tables with relationships in the logical layer. I renamed every pertinent column and made a couple calculated columns to replicate the results of the original flattened table I'm replacing.
I uploaded the new data source, overwriting the previous version. I had hoped that reports using this data source would see and successfully swap to the new columns of the exact same name, but that didn't happen. So I ended up replacing references to every column mentioned in a report page.
For all but two report pages, this ended up with me seeing the data as expected once the last column per page was updated.
For the last two, they still appeared blank. I attempted to remove filter columns or mark columns but data would not show.
I would end up adding a new data source, actually the exact same source, and replacing it with the copy of itself. This solved one of the two affected pages. The second page still showed nothing.
I decided to rebuild the affected page in a new page, column by column, filter by filter. Tableau crashed several times, but finally I had the new page completed and showing me data. When I added the new page to the dashboard, however, it showed as blank. When I went back to the new page, the data appeared greyed out. If I saved the workbook in this state, when I reload the workbook the new page shows blank just like the page it was based on.
What can I do about this?

Reiterating some steps:
I renamed every pertinent column and made a couple calculated columns to replicate the results of the original flattened table I'm replacing.
I had hoped that reports using this new data source would see and successfully swap to the new columns of the exact same name, but that didn't happen. So I ended up replacing references to every column mentioned in a report page.
For the two report pages appearing blank, I attempted to remove filter columns or mark columns but data would not show.
I hit "New data source" actually the exact same source and replaced it with the copy of itself. This solved one of the two affected pages. The second page still showed nothing.
I rebuilt the last page from scratch. When I added the new page to the dashboard, however, it showed as blank. When I went back to the new page, the data appeared greyed out. Afterwards this page will be blank too.

Check your dashboard actions, maybe there is a latent show hide somewhere; check if you have any sheets on your dashboard that you are using as a filter;  also check what sheets are using filters that applied across your entire datasource, if they are selected, they will hide data on other sheets if those sheets are using the same columns. If that's is not the cause, edit the question to include a screenshot of the blank sheet's column makeup (rows self, columns shelf, filter and mark pane)
